# How can I get tortoise-tts to pronounce acronyms correctly?

Tags: nlp, voice, text-to-speech

I'm trying to get [tortoise-tts](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts) to pronounce acronyms correctly. Example of text that I'd like tortoise-tts to generate an audio file for: `OpenAI ChatGPT is a new language model`.

The audio file generated by tortoise-tts is: `OpenAI Chat is a new language model` (GPT is missing from the [audio file](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/files/11176160/ChatGPT.became.Chat.zip)).

I can replace `ChatGPT` with `Chat gee pee tee` but I've had a case where the `jee pee tee` changes the tone of the audio file.

Questions:

1. Is replacing `ChatGPT` with `Chat gee pee tee` the most optimal solution?
2. If it is the most optimal solution, is there any convenient script to replace acronyms with their pronounced version (GPT->jee pee tee)?
3. If it is not the most optimal solution, what is the most optimal solution?